# Bootstrap 3 Modal not launching

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am having problems with implementing Bootstrap 3 Modal. I am just using the code given on the Bootstrap website.

Here is my Bootstrap code that I am testing:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Modal Test</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/stylish-portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <object type="application/pdf" data="SabareeshKappagantu.pdf" width="500" height="500">this is not working as expected</object>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<!--modal-->

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the jquery reference before the bootstrap reference.

Comment: Dang! I did not realize that. Fixed that! Thanks Steven!:)